# How many points does 'the-most-point-contained-circle' contain at least?

Tags: geometry, circles

> **Question** : Given any $n$ distinct points $S$, consider the $\binom n2$   discs $D_{pq}$ formed by picking a pair of points $p,q$ from $S$ and using them as a diameter. For each disc $D_{pq}$, let $N_{pq}$ be the number of points of $S$ on or inside $D_{pq}$. Let $N_S(n)$ be the largest $N_{pq}$, i.e. 
>   $$N_S(n)=\max\{N_{pq} :p,q\in S,p\not=q\}.$$
>   Let $f(n)$ be the minimum value of $N_S(n)$ when $S$ varies over the set of $n$ points. Then, how can we represent $f(n)$ by $n$ ?

**Remark** : A user achille hui got the following bounds for $n\gt 3$ :

$$\left\lceil \frac{n}{3}\right\rceil + 1 \le f(n) \le \left\lceil\frac{2n}{3}\right\rceil$$
This fixes $f(4)$ to $3$. (We have $f(3)=2$ trivially.)

The question comes from that I changed 'rectangle' to 'circle' in the following question I met a few weeks ago.

"When we place $n$ distinct points on the $xy$-plane, prove that there exists a rectangle, whose diagonal is closed by two of the $n$ points and whose edges are parallel to either $x$-axis or $y$-axis, has at least $\lfloor(n+1)/5\rfloor+1$ points inside or on the edges."

As a result, the question seems very difficult to me. Can anyone help?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195070/how-many-points-does-the-most-point-contained-circle-contain-at-least).

Comment: Suppose that someone only reads the "Question". then "Proposition 1" and "Proposition 2" come as a surprise; at least that's what I find. Are $f(n)$ , $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ integer valued functions? When reading the context, I may think so. In short: I don't understand much of your problem.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Well, I don't think the question is difficult to understand. $f(n)$ is an integer for any $n$, but $g(n),h(n)$ aren't necessarily. Consider the $n=3$ case. We have $f(3)\ge2$ in order that the proposition 1 is true. (In other words, if $f(3)\lt 2$, then the proposition 1 is false.) We also have $f(3)\le 2$ in order that the proposition 2 is true. (In other words, if $f(3)\gt 2$, then the proposition 2 is false.) Since we have $f(3)\ge 2$ and $f(3)\le 2$, we can conclude $f(3)=2$.

Comment: @mathlove: Can you provide a reference for the $\left\lfloor(n+1)/5\right\rfloor+1$ bound for the rectangular case?

Comment: What does it mean for the diameter of a circle to be closed by two points? Are you talking about the line segment between two points and do you want this to be the diameter of a circle? Then what stops you from taking the two points that are closest together and drawing a circle between them. Then no point will be inbetween. clearly I am not understanding something. Maybe you should elaborate a bit more. (the version with a rectangle talks about the existence of one rectangle - that is more believable than your version with "such that every circle"...)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Well, sadly, no I can't. I mean, I don't know if there is a reference. A friend of mine taught me the question.

Comment: @example: Yes, I'm talking about the line segment between two points of the $n$ points and I want this to be the diameter of a circle. Then, I think you don't understand the question. Taking one circle is not sufficient. Please read my above comment to HandeBruijn (the $n=3$ case). As you say, the way to ask the question is different from the version with a rectangle. In my opinion, the latter is easier to solve, but the former, which must be more difficult to solve, asks the minimum of the maximum for every set of $n$ points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer, I get following bounds for $n > 3$.

$$\left\lceil \frac{n}{3}\right\rceil + 1 \le f(n) \le \left\lceil\frac{2n}{3}\right\rceil\tag{*1}$$
In particular, this fixes $f(4)$ to $3$.

For any points $p,q,r \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let $\ell_{pq}$ be the line segment joining $p$ and $q$. Let $C_{pq}$ be the circle/disk having $\ell_{pq}$ as a diameter and $\triangle_{pqr}$ be the triangle formed by $p, q, r$.

For any set of $n$ points $S = \big\{\;p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n \;\big\}$ where $n > 3$.
Let $C_{min}$ be the [smallest circle/disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) covering $S$. It is known that 
$C_{min}$ is unique and one can determine it by at most 3 points from $S \cap \partial C_{min}$.

- If determined by $2$ points $p, q \in S \cap \partial C_{min}$, $\ell_{pq}$ is a diameter of $C_{min}$.
- If determined by $3$ points $p, q, r \in S \cap \partial C_{min}$, $\triangle_{pqr}$ is not obtuse.

If there exists $p,q \in S$ such that $\ell_{pq}$ is a diameter of $C_{min}$, then $C_{pq} = C_{min}$ covers $S$.
In this case,
$$| C_{pq} \cap S | = |S| = n\tag{*2a}$$

Otherwise, $C_{min}$ is determined by 3 points $p, q, r \in S$ and we can further assume $\triangle_{pqr}$ is an acute triangle. When $\triangle_{pqr}$ is an acute triangle, 
one can show that${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$
$$C_{pq} \cup C_{qr} \cup C_{rp} \supset C_{min} \supset S$$
This means one of $C_{pq}$, $C_{qr}$ and $C_{rp}$ contains at least  one third of elements
from $S \setminus \big\{\;p,q,r\;\big\}$. As a result, we get

$$\max\big\{\; |C_{pq} \cap S|, |C_{qr}\cap S|, |C_{rp} \cap S| \;\big\}
\ge \left\lceil \frac{n-3}{3} \right\rceil + 2 = \left\lceil \frac{n}{3} \right\rceil + 1\tag{*2b}$$

Combine $(*2a)$ and $(*2b)$, we get LHS of $(*1)$.

For the other direction of $(*1)$, one split $S$ into 3 groups $S_1, S_2, S_3$ with sizes
$$|S_1| = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor, 
|S_2|   = \left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{3} \right\rfloor\quad\text{ and }\quad
|S_3|   = \left\lfloor \frac{n+2}{3} \right\rfloor$$
One then place each group "near" the vertices of an equilateral triangle.
If one pick $p$ from $S_i$ and $q$ from $S_j$ and form the circle $C_{pq}$, it is clear
$C_{qp} \cap S \subset S_i \cup S_j$. This gives us

$$|C_{pq} \cap S| \le n - \min\big\{\; |S_1|, |S_2|, |S_3| \;\big\} = \left\lceil\frac{2n}{3}\right\rceil$$

Since this is true for all $p,q \in S$, this leads to RHS of $(*1)$.

**Notes and Details**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - To illustrate why $C_{pq} \cup C_{qr} \cup C_{rp} \supset C_{min}$, consider the picture at end.

  If one drop a perpendicular from $r$ to $pq$ and let $u$ be the corresponding foot, it is
  easy to see
  $$\triangle_{pqr} = \triangle_{pur} \cup \triangle_{ruq}
  \quad\text{ and }\quad  \triangle_{pur} \subset C_{rp} \quad( \text{ and similarly } \triangle_{ruq} \subset C_{qr} )
  $$
  The rest of $C_{min}$ splits into 3 lunes. Let consider the lune formed by the arc and chord joining $p$ to $r$. Let $v$ be any point on the arc $pr$. When $\triangle_{pqr}$ is an acute triangle, we have
  $$\phi = \measuredangle_{pqr} < \frac{\pi}{2}
  \quad\implies\quad \measuredangle_{rvp} = \pi - \phi > \frac{\pi}{2}$$
  This implies $v$ belongs to that part of semi-circle of $C_{pr}$ outside $\triangle_{pqr}$. 
  As a consequence, arc $pr$ lies inside $C_{pr}$. Since the corresponding lune
  is a convex hull of arc $pr$, $C_{pr}$ cover that lune. Same thing happens to other lunes.
  From this, we can conclude $C_{pq}, C_{qr}$ and $C_{rp}$ indeed cover $C_{min}$.

[image: Cover by 3 circles]

Comment: Very nice! I'm very happy to read this answer!

Comment: @mathlove you are welcome. the problem itself is interesting.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I'd like to ask you something. If you have any good ideas to improve the way to express the problem and the title, could you please show me them? (I mean, this problem has not received enough attention (even though the problem must be interesting in my opinion). I tried to do my best to express strictly what I want to ask, but I began to think that there might be a better way to ask this question (for example, without two propositions). Especially, the title might have to be changed. Maybe I should not ask such a question to others...)

Comment: @mathlove In its current form, it is indeed very hard to figure out what you are asking. If it is me, I will say something like this.

Given any $n$ distinct points $S$, consider the $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ discs $D_{pq}$
formed by picking a pair of points $p, q$ from $S$ and uses them as a diameter. 
For each disc $D_{pq}$, let $N_{pq}$ be the number of points of $S$ on or inside $D_{pq}$. Let $N_S$ be the largest $N_{pq}$, i.e.
$$N_{S} = \max \{ N_{pq} : p, q \in S, p \ne q \}$$

What is the minimum value of $N_{S}$ when $S$ varies over the set of $n$ points.  BTW, you title is fine.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. I'll edit as you suggest.